# Missing Bitcoin?

Tags: transactions, wallet, transaction-fees, unconfirmed-transactions

I am a Bitcoin newbie

I had some BTC transferred into my Breadwallet account on Dec 2nd and it showed up in my balance as confirmed. (Transaction ID: bcef79f0672705aa957dfa32982d504db28599289418a58c96d671842bf1e4d8). No problem.

I then transferred some more BTC from GDAX into my Breadwallet account on Dec 9th @ 16:02 . It showed as “In Progress" for a while and then it became confirmed and the amount was added to the total balance. (Transaction ID: b7194a8af423f4eb7a97b0af181203b074fa9b0b02b784fc1789c1d0beeea5b8)

I then sent some BTC from my Breadwallet on Dec 9th @ 18:44 which is now showing as “In Progress”. (Transaction ID: 6ad094d28c264d87d64512753916b76e9855f59194c18c636e87db234624fdc3)

The Economy network fee I paid for this transaction said that it would take 1 to 24hours. But it has been stuck at 40%.

Also, another issue I have is that the last receiving amount from GDAX that was confirmed on Dec 9th @ 16:02 is not showing in my Breadwallet now?

I don’t understand what is happening? Please help me as I am concerned that I have lost some Bitcoin.

What shall I do?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The transaction that isn't showing up in your wallet (txID b7194a8...) is okay, no need to worry. If you paste that txID into a block explorer website, you can see that the coins that were transferred have not moved since then. It may be that breadwallet is just out of sync/glitching. You can go to Menu->Settings->Sync Blockchain to try to remedy the situation. Don't worry if it doesn't work, your coins are safe.

For the unconfirmed tx, the network is rather congested right now. It is fine as well, an unconfirmed tx is at no risk of losing your coins, or anything like that. Give it time it will confirm

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have done the sync and it is now showing so that’s good news. In regards to waiting for the unconfirmed tx, will I be able to send BTC to any other addresses or do I need to wait for this to become confirmed first?

Comment: Yes, but it will depend on the software. If you have other unspent outputs in the wallet, you should be able to spend them while this tx is still unconfirmed.